# jQuery plugin html and options practices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, plugins

I am working on creating a jQuery plugin and I have some questions regarding how to structure things:

1.How much HTML should the plugin have written and how much should it create through jQuery ?

Is it good to have written all of the HTML so that the entirety of the markup structure is visible when looking over the code ?

Or is it better to have written only the minimum amount of HTML so that it is very easy for the user to add/modify content and create all of the rest, bulky HTML through jQuery ?

Is there a recommended practice ? How are things done in professional plugins ?

Why should things be done in a certain way and what are the reasons behind it ?

2.How to balance the plugin options with the CSS ?

Should the plugin offer options that would affect the presentation of the plugin (options that would modify the stylesheet) or is it a better practice to have the user directly modify the stylesheet for presentational modifications and in the plugin only have options relating to the functionality ?

What are some guides regarding what options to offer in the plugin as to not step over CSS ?

Regarding my experiences, I have seen all of these in different places and plugins and that is why I am asking for opinions from experienced users and what are good practices and why.

Comment: Stack Overflow usually involves some code. There are just too many questions there. I would start coding the plugin the best you can and come back for help if you need it. As for best practices the jquery API has a very good beginners guide on how to write plugins.

Comment: @elclanrs: There are only 2 questions, I don't think that is too many. And secondly, I have started coding it and am well underway. The reason why I am asking now is because I have seen that there are many possible options and I am trying to choose an option that is in concordance with common practices. What I am asking for are specific issues. Regarding the jQuery beginner's guide to writing plugins, I have read it, as well as several other guides but there are no recommendations for the structuring and separation of HTML, CSS and JS code.

Comment: If you want something more advanced this is the best you can probably find, a bit outdated but still relevant http://jqfundamentals.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. How much HTML should the plugin have written and how much should it create through jQuery ?**

According to the paradigms of progressive enhancement, there should be no markup which would be useless in case of no JS enabled. In other words - if your plugins needs some special markup and additional tags it should create them by itself.

The reasons for that is semantics. Additional plugin markup is useless for users (and bots) when there's no JS enabled and thus it should not be present at all.

Also keep in mind that developing a good JS plugin means that content will still be available when the plugin fails or JS is disabled. Moreover, you have to take additional care about making sure that your plugin is accessible. More on the topic of progressive enhancement covering also more advanced issues can be found for example in a book by [The Filament Group](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/announcing_our_book_designing_with_progressive_enhancement/).

**2. How to balance the plugin options with the CSS ?**

Do it as follows:

- Content: HTML
- Logic: JS
- Presentation: CSS

Despite the fact it's changing now a bit (think CSS3 animations), options of the plugin may influence the way it *works* rather than the way it *looks*. That means your users should be able to config timings, delays, speed, number of element or whatever your plugin is doing through JS. But leave the presentational aspects in the CSS stylesheet. Use JS to change classes of elements rather than inline styles and let your users write whatever CSS they want. Obviously, don't forget to provide some default styling :)

I always recommend reading more on the topic in [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understandingprogressiveenhancement/). It's quite a theoretical article but absolutely a must-read for any front-end dev.

Answer (score 0):

Tutsplus has a jQuery course with usefull videos.
http://tutsplus.com/lesson/head-first-into-plugin-development/

This is one of the videos that explaines how te make a plugin.
There are a lot of ways to create a plugin, but this is a good one.